# Cut out different elements from a string and put them into a list

Tags: java

Here's updated code. For those following along the question edits contains the original question.

```java
if (0 != searchString.length()) {
    for (int index = input.indexOf(searchString, 0); 
         index != -1; 
         index = input.indexOf(searchString, eagerMatching ? index + 1 : index + searchString.length())) {

        occurences++;
        System.out.println(occurences);

        indexIN=input.indexOf(ListStringIN, occurences - 1) + ListStringIN.length();
        System.out.println(indexIN);
        System.out.println(ListStringIN.length());

        indexOUT=input.indexOf(ListStringOUT, occurences - 1);
        System.out.println(indexOUT);

        Lresult.add(input.substring(indexIN, indexOUT));

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I gave me out the index numbers
My code works well with only one Element
But when I write something like this: `%%%%ONE++++ %%%%TWO++++`
There's this exception:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 16, end 7, length 23
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3410)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1883)
    at com.DMMS.Main.identify(Main.java:81)
```

And I found out that the indexIN changes in the Start of the second String but not the indexOUT
I couldn't find out why

Comment: your question isn't clear.

Comment: And please note: I am not accusing you of anything. Just saying that it is dangerous to rely on code that you don't understand.

Comment: When you edit the question out from under everyone nothing makes sense anymore. You can *add* code to a question, but now the answer thread is in response to a question that no longer exists. Questions are also not a comment thread.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can you somehow revert it to the original post?

Comment: @Bentaye Anybody w/ edit privileges can; I'm on mobile and don't want to try to edit the original and current question.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at your code you can notice: in the first loop that counts the number of occurrences, your code "knows" that it has to use that version of `indexOf()` that relies on **offsets** within the search strings.

In other words: you know that you have to search **after** previous "hits" when walking through your string.

But your second loop, the one that has to **extract** the actual things, there you are using `indexOf()` **without** that extra offset parameter. Therefore you keep "copying out" the same part repeatedly.

Thus: "simply" apply the same logic from loop 1 for loop 2!

Beyond that:

- you don't need two loops for that. Counting occurrences and "copying out" the matching code ... can be done in one loop
- and honestly: rewrite that first loop. This code is almost incomprehensible for human beings. A reader would have to sit down and read this 10, 20 times, and then run it in a debugger to understand what it is doing

Comment: I have to admit that I copied the code and I do not know exactly how it works, could you please help me a bit?

Comment: @TristanK. Sorry, but this community isn't a tutor service where people sit down with you and work with you through your problems. That is the thing: when you pick code from somewhere, but you want to use it in your project ... you better understand exactly what it is doing. My recommendation to you: throw that code away. Instead: write your own code. Start with a much simpler "syntax" where you have simple chars marking begin/end. Then write a string with 2, 3 "occurrences" and think how you would **manually** determine them ... and cut out the corresponding text.

Comment: It is really not that hard, and you learn **much** more when you write code to solve the problem yourself. In the end, it is your code. You have to understand it, and be able to maintain it. Which basically means: you **never** ever pull in code that is so complicated that you dont understand it.

Comment: I want to defend myself you're right but substring is the first thing i only copie and its part of a much bigger project from me I think i haven't to know exactly what i doesI only need it PLEASE DONT THINK THAT IM A COPY PASTE GUY

Comment: @TristanK. As said, I gave you a lengthy hint how to approach this issue. Throw away that code, and step by step write small tests ... and the code to make the tests pass. This is really a great opportunity to learn how to use TDD and junit.

Answer (score -1):

I dit it!

Heres the code:

```
.........................
static String ListStringIN = "%%%%";
static String ListStringOUT = "++++";

........................

else if (input.contains(ListStringIN) && input.contains(ListStringOUT)) {
        System.out.println("Identifiziere Liste...");

        String searchString = ListStringIN;
        int occurences = 0;
        boolean eagerMatching = false;
        if (0 != searchString.length()) {
            for (int index = input.indexOf(searchString, 0); index != -1; index = input
                    .indexOf(searchString, eagerMatching ? index + 1 : index + searchString.length())) {



                occurences++;


                System.out.println(occurences);

                indexIN=input.indexOf(ListStringIN, occurences - 1) + ListStringIN.length();

                System.out.println(indexIN);

                //indexOUT=input.indexOf(ListStringOUT, occurences);

                //indexOUT=input.indexOf(ListStringOUT, occurences - 1);

                indexOUT = input.indexOf(ListStringOUT, eagerMatching ? index + 1 : index + ListStringOUT.length());

                System.out.println(indexOUT);
                Lresult.add(input.substring(indexIN, indexOUT));

                System.out.println();
            }
        }


        //for (int i = 0; i <occurences; i ++) {
          //  Lresult.add(input.substring(input.indexOf(ListStringIN, 0) + ListStringIN.length(), input.indexOf(ListStringOUT)));
        //}

        result = Lresult.toString();

        return result;

    }
```

I hope this is useful for other people

@GhostCat Thanks for your advices!

Comment: No this isn’t useful to others without an explanation of what the code does and how it solves the problem

Comment: I'd also recommend removing unused code and spurious whitespace, and using Java naming conventions, all of which aid readability.